# t-sql --- Table aliases in merge into statements --- Which of these two is better and why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, alias

The only difference between the two following MERGE statements is that I leave out the Table aliases when I insert the values in the first one and I include it in the second one.

I figure that since the MERGE INTO and USING statements define the source and target tables, the default would be to insert into the target USING the values from the source, and therefore there would be no reason to use the aliases.

**Which is better and why? Any Performance Difference?...I guess I need to learn how the query optimizer works)**

Without explicit use of Table Aliases in VALUES:

```
MERGE INTO TargetSchema.TargetTable AS T
USING SourceSchema.SourceSchema As S 
ON S.Id = T.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT(
       [Id]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Another Column]   
      )

   VALUES(
       [Id]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Another Column]
      );
```

With explicit use of Table Aliases in VALUES:

```
MERGE INTO TargetSchema.TargetTable AS T
USING SourceSchema.SourceSchema As S 
ON S.Id = T.Id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT(
       [Id]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Another Column]   
      )

   VALUES(
       [S].[Id]
      ,[S].[Status]
      ,[S].[Another Column]
      );
```

Comment: Does the second syntax even work? There is no performance difference in using aliases or not.

Comment: My bad, it only works when the aliases are on "values" not on insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are mainly used for increasing the readability or for naming a calculated column .It does not have any impact on the performance of the query

Answer (score 1):

Aliases make no difference to performance

They arguable make a difference to readability and maintainability though